# How to update object list JDO

Tags: java, jdo, objectdb

So I'm trying to update an object called Alumno, this is the class:

```
 public class Alumno extends Persona {

 private Alumno alumno;


 private List<String> telefonos;


 private List<Asignatura> asignaturas;
```

And this is class "Asignatura"

```
public class Asignatura {

 private String alias;


 private String nombre;


 private Long curso;


 private Profesor profesor;


 private List<Alumno> alumnos;
```

And when I try to update an object "Alumno" I get this error:

> [ObjectDB 2.8.1] javax.jdo.JDOUserException
>   Object 'Modelo.Asignatura.Asignatura#'PGL'' belongs to another EntityManager [Asignatura:'PGL'] (error 634)

Any idea on how to solve this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates mixing entity objects of different `EntityManager` instances.

Every `EntityManager` instance represents a separate connection to the database with a separate and isolated "persistence context", which is the set of objects in memory that represent entity objects in the database.

If you retrieve an entity object in one `EntityManager` you are not allowed to link it to entity objects in another `EntityManager` instance (e.g. using references from another entity object of another `EntityManager`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I can't persist an object with a list of objects from another entity?

Comment: I fixed that. Now I get this error when I try to update the object "Alumno" with a new list of "Asignatura"                                                                                    Attempt to reuse an existing primary key value (Modelo.Asignatura.Asignatura:'ETS') (error 642)

Comment: So please accept the answer (mark it as accepted and vote for it) and create a new post for the new question.